# MSBuild and Visual Studio crash from wrong explicit interface declaration

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I've painfully stumbled into a way to make MSBuild.exe hard crash Visual Studio 2019. The reporting mechanism in VS2019 doesn't seem to work (won't sign in saying something like `The \"path\" argument must be of type string.`), and the webpage for reporting issues says to do it through VS, so I don't know where else to post this.

It could be my installation that is the issue, and not the compiler, but I do seem to be able to hang the C# compiler online with this as well. Running a repair install did not help. I think it may be the new C# 8 compiler specifically, since the older compiler does seem to give a correct `explicit interface declaration can only be declared in a class or struct` compilation error instead of timing out.

It's really easy to cause, so be careful, since as soon as you type this out it hard crashes VS. You don't even need to save the file or hit build, the on-demand compiler kills VS the moment you type this out.

If you do manage to save your file then VS will die as soon as the file is on-demand compiled (so, immediately on startup if the file is already open, or as soon as you manually open the file). If you saved the file, refrain from opening it, and then hit build, you can see that the build fails due to a stack overflow exception. VS doesn't die in this case.

Normal interface (no problem so far):

```
public interface ITest {
   int Property { get; }
}
```

Hard crash (MSBuild gets stack overflow and VS2019 doesn't handle it very well):

```
public interface ITest {
   int ITest.Property { get; }
}
```

If anyone can (or can't) replicate this (should be easy to test) let me know and maybe you could report it to MS instead.

Comment: Maybe it's an obvious question, but why do you need to write such code? I mean member with explicit interface declaration itself

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't need to, but if you happen to type or paste it, it immediately hard crashes VS. For example, maybe you just typed out an explicit implementation of something you're planning to pull up into an interface. So you copy the explicit implementation and paste it into the interface, planning to delete the explicit part. But you can't get that far because VS dies. It should be a compile-time error, but instead the compiler is getting a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated answer]

Hi Dave,

We are working to get the sign in issue addressed. Our team has a fix in the latest preview (V16.4 preview 5). If you can give that a try to report and let us know how that goes. If you see an error, please send me the full error text. You can download the preview here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

I have also created a report for you as a workaround. Here is the link where you can track it.  Please visit the link and vote on the issue so you can get notifications on progress:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/825095/msbuild-and-visual-studio-crash-from-wrong-explici.html

Thanks
Sean

Visual Studio Feedback Systems

Comment: I have 16.3.9, but I still get the issue. Big long stack trace with the message `Error signing in: '{"stack":"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined`. Maybe it's related to IE version or something. I'm on Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: I've now updated to 16.4 and the submit feedback feature does now seem to be working.